# How to write data in multiple nested dictionary into a .csv or .txt file in table format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I wrote a script to read data from a file and store them in 3 dictionaries.

For example,

```
d1 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'}, 'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
d2 = {'Ben': {'Strength': 'wo_mana', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Speed': 'wo_mana'}, 'Tom': {'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Agility': 'wo_mana'}}
d3 = {'Ben': {'Strength': '1.10', 'Int': '1.20', 'Speed': '1.50'}, 'Tom': {'Int': '1.40', 'Agility': '1.60'}}
```

Then, I wish to write the data into a .csv or .txt file in table format so that when I open the output file with Excel, it has 5 columns and 4 rows which will look like this:

```
Name Skill Magic wo_mana          wi_mana
Ben  true  false Strength = 1.10  Int = 1.20
                 Speed = 1.50
Tom  true  true  Agility = 1.60   Int = 1.40
```

It doesn't matter whether Ben or Tom data comes first.

Given that I know how I want my header looks like, here is what I have tried so far:

```
import csv, itertools

header = ['Name', 'Skill', 'Magic', 'wo_mana', 'wi_mana']

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, header)
    w.writeheader()
    for key, val in sorted(d1.items()):
        row = {'Name': key}
        row.update(val)
        w.writerow(row)
```

and my output is:

```
Name,Skill,Magic,wo_mana,wi_mana
Ben,true,false,,
Tom,true,true,,
```

which is correct for the first 3 columns.

Now, I do not know how to write the data for `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` columns because:

a) the `Speed = 1.50` or `Strength = 1.10` must be in the third row since they belong to `Ben`, so there will be two rows under the `wo_mana` column for `Ben`, should I merge `d2` and `d3` such that

```
d23 = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': 'Strength = 1.10', 'wo_mana': 'Speed = 1.50', 'wi_mana': 'Int = 1.20'}, 'Tom': {'wo_mana': 'Agility = 1.60', 'wi_mana': 'Int = 1.40'}}
```

b) I do not know how to print out all the data row-by-row (print all data for Ben first then Tom or vice versa), because the `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` data are not in the same dictionary as `Skill` and `Magic`

Should I do some changes to the 3 dictionaries first before writing them straight away to the output file? What should I do to achieve my desired output? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. It wouldn't make sense to have multiple rows for a record in csv so add both the lines to one. For example: `Strength = 1.10; Speed = 1.50`

So first store your result in a list and then join the list with `;`(or any char other then `,`)

2. Since you have multiple dictionaries to parse, parse them one by one and add them to a single list so that you get it all in row order.

Comment: 1) You mean it's impossible to write multiple rows in .csv file? And should I convert all the dictionaries to lists? Is it easier if I combine `d2` and `d3` to `d23 = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10', 'Speed = 1.50'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20']}, 'Tom': {'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.40'], 'wo_mana': ['Agility = 1.60']}}` 2) May I know how to add them to a single list? What should the list looks like?

Comment: Its not impossible, it just wouldn't make sense to do it. Your list should be created my parsing all the dictionaries and forming [val1, val2, val3...]

Comment: Alright, I will try with string formatting since I am required to obtain a table where there are multiple rows for a field

Comment: CSVs are supposed to have a record per line. You could however make it 2, but the file would have records like `a,b,c` then `"",d,""`.

Comment: Are you saying the second row should be `,,,speed = 1.50,`? The data I got are from extracting them from a file, so I do not know the actual number of keys and values, hence I do not know how many rows for that field. How am I supposed to keep track of how many rows needed for that field and then tell `csv` to align it to that field? `wo_mana` and `wi_mana` can have multiple rows

Comment: Then its best to just keep a single row and concatenate multiple row values to it(in appropriate column).

Comment: I am trying to use `string formatting` instead of `csv` because I am required to show multiple rows for my table. However, I am also struggling with `string formatting`. I have moved this problem to another post, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38080975/python-writing-multiple-nested-dictionaries-in-one-table-in-a-text-file-separat), please try and see whether you can help me if it's possible.